# Android making actionbar overlay on grid view

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-gridview

I have already implemented `ActionBar Overlay` using this [Overlaying the Action Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html)

In my `Fragment`, I have a `GridView` defined as

```
<GridView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize" />
```

And In my `styles.xml` file I have done

```
 <style name="Widget.ActionBar.Transparent">
    <item name="android:background">#55000000</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBarTransparent" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.ActionBar.Transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

But when I scroll up the `GridView`, the `ActionBar` doesn't seem transparent i.e. no grid view items are seen below the `ActionBar`. But when I remove the `android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"`,from `layout` file, I do see transparent `ActionBar`.So, what is the way to properly show `ActionBar Overlay` for a `GridView`. I want to achieve the gallery select effect as of `Tumblr Android App`. Following is the attached screenshot[image: Tumblr Gallery Image Selection]

Comment: Have you tried android:clipToPadding="false"?

Comment: Thanks @sandrstar your provided suggestion works for me.

Answer (score 1):

As per the suggestion provided by @sandrstar , doing `android:clipToPadding=false`,solved my issue. So on my `layout.xml`,I have to write the following

```
<GridView 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:clipToPadding="false"
  android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize" />
```

Thanks @sandrstar